# Recursivity in Racket to create a list of coordinates

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to create a function that returns a list of coordenates in the for of pairs such as: (0.0) (0.1)...(rows.columns). It goes to an infinite loop and i don't know why. Any suggestion?

```
(define (generate-positions-rec rows columns)
  (cond [(and (= rows 0) (= columns 0)) empty]
        [else (cons rows columns)
              (generate-positions-rec (- rows 1)(- columns 1))]
        ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will go into a recursive loop if it's invoked with a negative number or one of the parameters is greater than the other. We can fix this issue with a proper base case.

But you're not actually *building* a list as output, the call to `cons` is lost. This is what you meant to do, notice how you need to `cons` the new pair of coordinates to the result of the recursive call:

```
(define (generate-positions-rec rows columns)
  (cond [(or (<= rows 0) (<= columns 0)) empty]
        [else (cons (cons rows columns)
                    (generate-positions-rec (- rows 1)(- columns 1)))]))
```

This is how it works now:

```
(generate-positions-rec 4 3)
=> '((4 . 3) (3 . 2) (2 . 1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how to store it as a variable to use it in other functions?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Store "what" thing as a variable? What "other" functions are you referring to?

Comment: How can i make a variable that stores the list of coordinates in a recursive way?
Such as something like this:
(define (generate-positions rows columns)
  (define all-positions (for*/list ([i rows][j columns]) (cons i j)))
  (let ([initial-state (get-initial-state)]
        [end-state (get-end-state rows columns)])
  (remove initial-state (remove end-state all-positions))))

Comment: I'm afraid the question is still not clear. Please post it as a new question, providing a sample input and the expected output.